# Android: custom layout DialogFragment doesn't respect the width size given

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I've created this class:

```
public class AlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_alert, container);
    ...
```

My dialog_alert.xml layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/dialog_background">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/keyline_4"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/keyline_4"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/keyline_4">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/DialogTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/visible_by"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        style="@style/DialogContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vos données de connexion sont incorrectes." />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/keyline_4"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/keyline_1"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/keyline_1"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/negative_button"
        style="@style/DialogButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/keyline_0"
        android:text="negative"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/positive_button"
        style="@style/DialogButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="positive" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the result is:

[image]

I've defined "match_parent" attribute with the padding equal at 24dp (=@dimen/keyline_4).

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: I don't know if this will work for DialogFragment, but it does for a Dialog.        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        getWindow().setAttributes(params);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

Comment: Hi, please how did you solve it ?